# Regarding flex arraycollection

Tags: apache-flex

Im trying to get the commands in the array collection in the fx:string heres apart of the code I want it to exit when i click on exit

```
                <s:ArrayCollection>
                    <fx:String>Settings</fx:String> 
                    <fx:String>Email Us</fx:String>
                    <fx:String>About</fx:String>
                    <fx:String>Exit</fx:String>
                </s:ArrayCollection>
                </s:List>

        </s:calloutContent>
    </s:CalloutButton>
</s:navigationContent>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<s:List id="menulst" change="if(menulst.selectedItem == 'Exit')nativeApplication.exit();">
    <s:ArrayCollection>
        <fx:String>Settings</fx:String> 
        <fx:String>Email Us</fx:String>
        <fx:String>About</fx:String>
        <fx:String>Exit</fx:String>
    </s:ArrayCollection>
</s:List>
```

Or you can also write a click event for the list component and write such codes over there too. `nativeApplication.exit()` is the best way to exit from the Application.

Comment: now another problem heres the entire part of the code just keeps saying nativeapplication acces of undefined property nativeApplication then under that change.

Comment: kindly provide some more info about what exactly is required.. so that I could help you out..

Comment: is the screen where you do the changes is `WindowedApplication`.. If yes, then `nativeApplication.exit()` would do good.. If not, then try `NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit()`.. Also do `import flash.desktop.NativeApplication;` over the top

Comment: Thanks a lot.. If you have got the solution for your question.. Kindly tick it as answer..